# Rails 3.2 using JRuby on Solaris

Tags: jruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, solaris-10

Has anyone managed to get Rails 3.2 working on Solaris-10 with JRuby?

We appear to be caught in a nasty dependency vortex.  Rails 3.2 requires JRuby 1.6.6 or later, according to: [Using JRuby with Rails 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072070/using-jruby-with-rails-3-2)

But JRuby 1.6.5 is the last version that can successfully install gems on Solaris: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6494

Is it possible that there is a patch out there or something we haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1):

We have a Rails 3.2.2 app working on Solaris. We're using JRuby 1.6.5.1 and the latest warbler, but we had to downgrade jruby-rack to 1.1.5 I believe.

What doesn't work is asset compilation, because we haven't found a working javascript runtime. Node.js doesn't support Solaris Sparc, and therubyracer had compilation issues we didn't spend too much time trying to resolve. So we currently precompile assets on local development workstations (Windows). We're not really using the asset pipeline (and I'm not convinced it was a good idea to make it the Rails default), so we may disable it so that we can run a CI build on Solaris.

Here's the gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.2)
      actionpack (= 3.2.2)
      mail (~> 2.4.0)
    actionpack (3.2.2)
      activemodel (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.1)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.1.2)
    activemodel (3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.2)
      activemodel (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.2.2)
    activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter (1.2.2)
      activerecord-jdbc-adapter (~> 1.2.2)
      jdbc-sqlite3 (~> 3.7.2)
    activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.4.1)
    activeresource (3.2.2)
      activemodel (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
    activesupport (3.2.2)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0146.1)
    builder (3.0.0)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    jdbc-sqlite3 (3.7.2)
    journey (1.0.3)
    jquery-rails (2.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    jruby-openssl (0.7.6.1)
      bouncy-castle-java (>= 1.5.0146.1)
    json (1.6.5)
    json (1.6.5-java)
    mail (2.4.3)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.17.2)
    multi_json (1.1.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.2)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.2)
      actionpack (= 3.2.2)
      activerecord (= 3.2.2)
      activeresource (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.2)
    railties (3.2.2)
      actionpack (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.1.15)
    sass-rails (3.2.4)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.1.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    therubyrhino (1.73.1)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.32)
    uglifier (1.2.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
```

I'm hopeful that the JRuby team will spend some time making JRuby 1.7 work on Solaris. Otherwise we'll have to accelerate our migration to linux...